# jquery .blur not working with morethen one textboxes. Firing on both fucus in and out

Tags: asp.net, jquery, blur

I am using jQuery `.blur` on ASP.NET's `Textbox` controls. My jQuery code is as bellow.

Problem is if I change the focus from `TextBox1` to `TextBox2` or vice versa. It fires both jQuery functions. But I only want them to fire when the focus the control loose the focus. Its working fine on one TextBox. But with two or more, on focus change it fire two functions.

Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance.

Regards

```
 $("#MainContent_TextBox1").blur(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: document.location.pathname + '/Test',
                data: '{name: "' + $("#MainContent_TextBox1").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
    });

    $("#MainContent_TextBox2").blur(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: document.location.pathname + '/Test',
                data: '{name: "' + $("#MainContent_TextBox2").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
    });
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Text box 1"></asp:TextBox><br />
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="Text box 2"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="Text box 3"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /><br />
```

**Browser Source**

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1" type="text" value="Text box 1"     id="MainContent_TextBox1" class="myclass" /><br />
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox2" type="text" value="Text box 2" id="MainContent_TextBox2" class="myclass" /><br />
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox3" type="text" value="Text box 3" id="MainContent_TextBox3" class="myclass" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Button1" value="Button" id="MainContent_Button1" /><br />


<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu',     disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't the `alert` steal focus from the second element and trigger the second `blur()` handler?

Comment: hi @bububaba, that could be the case. I will investigate. Thanks

Comment: No thats not the case. I have commented out the alerts and it still hitting the breakpoint twice.

Comment: @Hayer OK - thats not HTML thats ASP ... what I wanted was what is output to the browser - ie view source .... have a look at my answer - with a simple example everything works as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly i would change your code .... to simplify it use a `class` on the TextBox control then do :

```
$('.yourclass').blur(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: document.location.pathname + '/Test',
        data: '{name: "' + $(this).val() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Then you dont have to create lots and lots of `blur` methods !

[Here is an exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/V7YuJ/) - and on this example you can see that the `blur` method works fine

Comment: Hi @ManseUK, Now I am using exactly the same way you suggested. But its still behaving like it was previously.

Comment: @Hayer have you looked at the working demo i included - I can only suggest that your breakpoint / alerts are causing the problem - try outputting to a `div` like in my demo instead of breakpoints or alerts

Comment: thanks @ManseUK, you was right. Alerts and breakpoints were creating the problems. Being a c# developer I love breakpoints :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#MainContent_TextBox1").bind('blur',function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: document.location.pathname + '/Test',
                data: '{name: "' + $("#MainContent_TextBox1").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
    });

    $("#MainContent_TextBox2").bind('blur',function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: document.location.pathname + '/Test',
                data: '{name: "' + $("#MainContent_TextBox2").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: `blur()` is a shortcut to `.bind('blur')` ... see http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.blur